# How to update JTableModel after the sorter has changed the rows order?

Tags: java, swing, sorting, jtable

I have implemented a JTable, on which I can search entries with a textField.

When a request is made, my code gets the `DefaultTableModel`, looks for the element in each column and row, and then sets the selection in the table to the line where the element was found.

This works, but it's useless if I sort the table by clicking on any column, because the sorting doesn't seem to update the `DefaultTableModel`.

The table is part of a bigger project which is **extremely** complicated and full of dependencies so I cannot post a small example, but I think this will sum it up:

Given a `DefaultTableModel A` full of non-sorted data about a `JTable B`, where `B.setAutoCreateRowSorter()` is `true` , how does one update `B` after several/any cloumn-sortings of `A`?

I have read the docs and also looked into this:

http://www.codejava.net/java-se/swing/6-techniques-for-sorting-jtable-you-should-know

As well as dug a bit into `TableRowSorter#addRowSorterListener`, but it can only tell me that a column was sorted, not really useful. Unless of course I use what that column is to try and sort all the values in a multidimensional array, then clear the table, then assign everything back.. but clearly this is extremely slow for and not really an option in my case.

Refer to this for the info provided by a `RowSorterEvent`:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/RowSorterEvent.html

Can someone point me in the right direction ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> When a request is made, my code gets the DefaultTableModel, looks for the element in each column and row...

So don't search the TableModel. You can use the table.getValueAt(...) method to search for the element in each row/column of the table. The data will be accessed in the currently sorted order of the table.

> because the sorting doesn't seem to update the DefaultTableModel.

Correct, only the View (JTable) is updated.

If you want to keep searching the TableModel directly then you need to convert the model indexes to the view indexes whenever you want to invoke a JTable method (ie. selecting a table row). This is done by using the following `JTable` methods:

```
int columnColumn = table.convertColumnIndexToView(modelColumn);
int row = table.convertRowIndexToView(modelRow);
```

There are also methods to convert the view values to the model values.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, fixed all my issues.